# Received Uncaught TypeError: budgetArray.push is not a function, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I think I know what the issue is, I suspect its this causing the issue?

```
let budgetArray =  JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");
```

This is basically getting the stored data from here

```
/*----Store Stored budget list----*/
function storedEntry(){

    const saveData = makeNewBudget();
    const myJSON = JSON.stringify(saveData);
    window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, myJSON);
 
}
```

The `makenewbudget()` is a function that contains an object of user input data

```
function makeNewBudget(){
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    cashflowNew: el.cashflow.value,
    catagoryNew: el.catagory.value,
    labelNew: el.label.value,
    dateNew: createdDate(),
    numberNew: el.number.value,
  };
  return data;
}
```

I have a function that when you click the create budget button its meant to add to the list

```
/*----form validation----*/
let budgetButton = document.querySelector(".budget-button");

let label = document.querySelector(".label");
let num = document.querySelector(".number");
let entry = document.querySelector(".entry")

budgetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {

  if (!label.value || !num.value) {
    alert("please make sure all inputs are filled");
  }
  
  budgetArray.push(makeNewBudget())

  renderList();

  storedEntry();

});
```

This is the `renderList()` function

```
/*----Render Budget List----*/
function renderList(){
el.list.innerHTML = budgetArray.map(function (data,i) {

  return `<div class="entry">
  <div class="list">
    <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="Archive" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/archive.png" alt="Archive">
      </button>
      <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}" class = "edit" data-id="${data.id}">
          <img src="../resources/Images/edit.png" alt="Edit">
      </button>

      <div class="input" data-id="${data.id}"></div>
      <label class="dateNew">${data.dateNew}</label>
      <label class="cashflowNew">${data.cashflowNew}</label>
      <label class="catagoryNew">${data.catagoryNew}</label>
      <label class="labelNew">${data.labelNew}</label>
      <label class="numberNew">${data.numberNew}</label>
  </div>
</div>
<label class="total"></label>`;
});

}
```

I am not sure what I can do to fix the `Uncaught TypeError: budgetArray.push is not a function`

The error does not appear if I change

```
let budgetArray =  JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");
```

to

```
let budgetArray = [];
```

So I am a bit stumped in how to fix that, because The `localStorage.getItem` needs to check the array for the stored data.

Comment: `saveData` is not an array, but a plain object. So you're not writing an array as JSON to local storage. That means reading it and parsing it, will also not produce an array.

Comment: to elaborate: the problem is that `budgetArray` is an *object*, not an *array* (assuming the call to localstorage succeeds). And objects don't have a `.push` method.

Comment: ah okay, so I am not sure how to change the saveData to an array?

Comment: @Sheldon If you need an object, then just use an object. Why must it be an array? just don't use `.push`

Comment: Oh wait, you want budgetArray to be an array of objects? but you only ever store a single object at a time!

Comment: yes exactly, it has to be an array. so how would I go about storing more than on object at a time?

Comment: You probably want to first *read* the array from local storage (but make sure to first delete it now -- to have a clean situation), then push `saveData` to that array, and write that array back as JSON to local storage.

Comment: you'll have to make saveData into an array objects as well

Comment: Never write `saveData` to local storage, but `budgetArray`.